# Updating a JList with Files

Tags: java, swing, file, file-io, jlist

I'm trying to make a little program for a school project that extracts files. I'm using a JList to display all the extracted files but after lots of hours lurking I can't figure out how to make this JList update when there are new files present in the folder. It doesn't refresh properly in the button's ActionListener since the batch file (the actual extractor) takes a varied amount of time to finish. How can I get this to work?

This is the class I'm using to find files of certain extension:

```
public class fileFinder {
    public static String[] thing() {
        File file = new File(".\\at9snfsbs");
        File[] files = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                if (name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".at9")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        String[] fileNames = new String[files.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            fileNames[i] = files[i].getName();
        }

        return fileNames;
    }

}
```

This is the JList:

```
        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        String[] things = fileFinder.thing();
        for (int i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
            model.addElement(things[i]);
        }
        JList list = new JList(model);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
```

And this is a button's ActionListener that starts a batch file which is the actual converter:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start .\\at9snfsbs\\shit.bat");
    String[] thang = fileFinder.thing();
    model.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < thang.length; i++) {
        model.addElement(thang[i]);
    };
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm not experienced or good in coding so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Andrew Thompson: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

I got it working with a `ProcessBuilder` and `waitFor()`.